# How to skip maven phase pre-integration-test if skipITs is set?

Tags: maven, integration-testing, maven-failsafe-plugin, maven-lifecycle

I have some integration tests that depend on test data. This test data is created in phase `pre-integration-test` and removed in phase `post-integration-test`.

My problem is that these phases are still executed if I use `-DskipITs` on the Maven commandline.

Is there any way to make `-DskipITs` also skip the pre-integration-test and post-integration-test phases?

This is the plugin definition in the pom:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>sql-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.5</version>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<configuration>
    <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
    <url>${database.url}</url>
    <username>${database.user}</username>
    <password>${database.pw}</password>
</configuration>

<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>create-integration-test-data</id>
        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>execute</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <orderFile>descending</orderFile>
            <fileset>
                <basedir>${basedir}/src/test/resources/sql</basedir>
                <includes>
                    <include>AdministrationTestTeardown.sql</include>
                    <include>AdministrationTestSetup.sql</include>
                </includes>
            </fileset>
        </configuration>
    </execution>

    <execution>
        <id>remove-data-after-test</id>
        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>execute</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <fileset>
                <basedir>${basedir}/src/test/resources/sql</basedir>
                <includes>
                    <include>AdministrationTestTeardown.sql</include>
                </includes>
            </fileset>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: What plugin(s) are bound to the pre-integration-test and post-integration-test phases?

Comment: Please show your pom file!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a profile activated by the presence of `skipITs` and the `<skip>` option of the Maven plugin to skip the execution of the plugin entirely. There are several ways of doing this.

---

### Set a property to check later

You can set a Maven property inside the profile, then use that property to skip actions.

```xml
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>skip-integration-test-data-creation</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>skipITs</name>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <skip-integration-test-data-creation>true</skip-integration-test-data-creation>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

-

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>sql-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    ...
    <skip>${skip-integration-test-data-creation}</skip>
    ...
</plugin>
```

### Put the plugins into their own profile

Another solution is to put all `<plugin>` sections that should not run into a seperate profile, and disable that profile when `-DskipITs` is active.

```xml
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>skip-integration-test-data-creation</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <!-- Disable profile if skipITs is set -->
                <name>!skipITs</name>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
<!-- Here: All plugins that should not run if skipITs is set -->
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: Hi, good answer! You were faster than me, so I took the liberty of adding my solution to your answer. That way it reads nicer than a second answer.

Comment: Fine by me, but I thought the point of multiple answers was to provide different solutions (from which the OP may choose the one that best fits his needs). Anyway, you have way more experience than I do. Funny, that we both "raced" to provide an answer for a question from 2014 ;-)

Comment: Yes, you have a point about multiple answers. I guess a second answer would have been ok as well - it's just that the answers are very similar, so I thought I'd combine them.

Answer (score 18):

Better way is to use the **skipITs** property to skip the execution of both pre-integration & post-integration phases.

In your case, it will look like :

```
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>create-integration-test-data</id>
        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>execute</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <skip>${skipITs}</skip>
            <orderFile>descending</orderFile>
            <fileset>
                <basedir>${basedir}/src/test/resources/sql</basedir>
                <includes>
                    <include>AdministrationTestTeardown.sql</include>
                    <include>AdministrationTestSetup.sql</include>
                </includes>
            </fileset>
        </configuration>
    </execution>

    <execution>
        <id>remove-data-after-test</id>
        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>execute</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <skip>${skipITs}</skip>
            <fileset>
                <basedir>${basedir}/src/test/resources/sql</basedir>
                <includes>
                    <include>AdministrationTestTeardown.sql</include>
                </includes>
            </fileset>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

So, whenever you run mvn command with **-DskipITs**, it will skip the integration test as well the execution of this plugin.

Comment: Is it a default property for this plugin? Your solution worked but my IDE says it cannot resolve the symbol `skipITs`. 
IDE - IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2

Comment: You can ignore the IDE, it's just not aware of the implementation details of the plugin.  You can put `<!--suppress UnresolvedMavenProperty -->` right above that line so IntelliJ ignores it too.

Comment: Great solution, but it can be improved. If we use the generic property to not execute tests (skipTests), when we indicate that we do not want tests following the standard, the plugins that we configure with: <skip>${skipTests}</skip> will not be executed either.